# Can't pip install pathlib on M1 Mac

Tags: python, pip, pathlib

When I run `pip install pathlib==1.0.1` I get the following error:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/4l/rwj9f3x12qs0nbw_dq3prw2c0000gn/T/pip-install-g5u_0nde/pathlib_adb255351e05488f95986f7a8775e1f0/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
          setup(
        File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/folder/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 109, in setup
          _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
        File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/folder/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 460, in __init__
          for ep in metadata.entry_points(group='distutils.setup_keywords'):
        File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/folder/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 999, in entry_points
          return SelectableGroups.load(eps).select(**params)
        File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/folder/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 449, in load
          ordered = sorted(eps, key=by_group)
        File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/folder/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 997, in <genexpr>
          dist.entry_points for dist in unique(distributions())
        File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/folder/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 609, in entry_points
          return EntryPoints._from_text_for(self.read_text('entry_points.txt'), self)
        File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/folder/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 917, in read_text
          return self._path.joinpath(filename).read_text(encoding='utf-8')
      AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'read_text'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

Any idea how to solve the error? Version 1.0.1 is the version I need and I have seen m1 laptops with pathlib version 1.0.1 on them

Answer (score 2):

`pathlib` has been part of the `stdlib` since python 3.4, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and also the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib/#description). Consequently, what you are seeing is just an incompatibility of installing the ancient package from pypi (2014) to a rather recent python version (3.9). You should not need to install it at all to your python version.

I don't know what the other laptopts you have seen had, but if for some reason they needed a legacy setup of e.g. python 2.7, then it would be sensible that they had `pathlib` installed separately via pip